# Inspecting the model in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning some Ruby on Rails, and am a newbie. Most of my background is in ASP.net MVC on the back end.

As I play with a basic scaffold project, I wonder about this case: you jump into an established Rails project and want to get to know the model. Based on what I have seen so far (again, simple scaffold), the properties for a given class are not immediately revealed. I don't see property accessors on the model classes.

I do understand that this is because of the dynamic nature of Ruby and such things are not necessary or even perhaps desirable. Convention over code, I get that. (Am familiar with dynamic concepts, mostly via JS.)

But if I am somewhere off in a view, and want to quickly know whether the (eg) Person object has a MiddleName property, how would I find that out? I don't have to go into the migrations, do I?

Comment: Have you tried using the rails console?

Answer (score 4):

ActiveRecord provides the attributes method, which returns a hash of attribute names mapped to their values for the receiving object. So you can do something like (example console session):

```
> u = User.first
> u.attributes
=> {"first_name"=>"Joe", "last_name"=>"Bloggs","email"=>"joe@bloggs.com"}
> u.attributes.keys
=> ["first_name", "last_name", "email"]
> u.attributes.keys.include?("middle_name")
=> false
```

[Documentation link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the attributes of a model in `schema.rb` if you want the full list of attributes on a model, including association ids.  Alternatively, there are many ways to do it in the console, such as `pp Model.instance` or `puts @instance.ai`, which show the same thing.  However, that won't give you the *methods* available, since rails does a lot of work to extrapolate methods from attributes (for instance, setting a `has_one :user` does more than just include `@instance.user`).

If you want to look at your available methods on an object or model, you can use `@instance.public_methods`.  You can subtract out inherited methods as well, e.g. `@instance.public_methods - Object.public_methods` or `@instance.public_methods - ActiveRecord::Base.public_methods`.  You can also use `.instance_methods` on the class, for instance.

Finally, you may want to look at the [annotate gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/annotate), which add comments to your models.  You have to rerun it after migrations but it might be what you're looking for